# how to get related posts where atleast 3 tag should be matched to current post in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to get similar (related) posts that should be matching atleast 3 tags (all post have more then 10 tags).  Is this possible? if yes please help. I have no idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    $rTag = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
    foreach($rTag as $individual_tag) $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;
        $related = get_posts( array( 
                'tax_query' => array(
                  array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                    'field'    => 'term_id',
                    'terms'    => $tag_ids,
                  ),
                ),
                'numberposts' => -1,
                'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
              ) ); 
?>
<section id="discover">
    <h2>Related posts</h2>
    <div class="singlepost">
        <?php  if( $related )  foreach( $related as $post ) {
      setup_postdata($post); 
                $tag_count = 0;
                $tag_min_match = 3;
                    foreach ( $tag_ids as $tag ) {
                        if ( has_tag( $tag ) && $tag_count < $tag_min_match ) {
                            $tag_count ++;
                        }
                    }
                if ($tag_count >= $tag_min_match) {
                    echo '<h4>'. get_the_title() .'</h4>';
                }
            }
        wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </div>
</section>
```